# Pytest: passing fixture result to parameters in parametrized test

Tags: python, parameters, pytest, fixtures

I have a file `test.py`:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3'])
def must_run_once(request):
  print("Setting up")
  yield request.param
  print("Tearing down")

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
  'parameter', 
  ['qx', 'rx', 'zx']
)
def test_parametrized(must_run_once, parameter):
  assert len(parameter) == 2
```

In lines 4 and 5 I define a fixture parametrized with a list of strings. In real life this fixture is time-consuming and only needs to run once. In line 7 the fixture returns the value of the current parameter with a `yield` statement.

In lines 10-14 I define a test which uses this fixture, but also has its own parameters. Currently the test only asserts the length of its own parameters in line 15. However, I'd like for it to also check the returned parameter from the fixture `must_run_once`, such that the assertions go  as follows:

```
# First run
assert len("p1") == 2
assert len("qx") == 2
assert len("rx") == 2
assert len("zx") == 2

# Second run
assert len("p2") == 2
assert len("qx") == 2
assert len("rx") == 2
assert len("zx") == 2

# Third run
assert len("p3") == 2
assert len("qx") == 2
assert len("rx") == 2
assert len("zx") == 2
```

Is there any way to achieve this in `pytest`?

Comment: How about `assert len(must_run_once) ==2`?

Comment: That wouldn't result in the same order of assertions which I provided in the question...

Comment: The order provided in the question won't work, because you have 9 independent test runs, not 3.

Comment: @user32882 : Curious, if you did manage to find the solution for this one?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not

Comment: But, why should the fixture param need to be `asserted`?